# Google Blogger Gadgets Changing HTML Code By Adding Forward

Tags: html, widget, blogger, google-gadget

I am trying to add a few widgets linked to external websites on a Google Blogger page. I am adding these widgets into Blogger Gadgets on the sides of the page.

When I copy and paste the widget code into the gadget and then hit save I notice that there is a "/" being added in certain places in the code. In one instance this is keeping the widget from updating with new information and for another widget I think it is keeping the widget from updating properly.

An example is "img src="http://www.hamqsl.com/solarn0nbh.php?image=random" /". The "/" at the end is not there when I place the code in the gadget. After I save it and look at it again the "/" is there. This is keeping the widget that this code links to from ever updating. The widget maker even advises against placing special characters into the code to prevent this issue.

How can I stop these "/"s from being added? I asked this question on the Blogger help forum but was directed here.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Any help on this?